# Post JSON to Python CGI

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax

I have got Apache2 Installed and Python working.

I am having a problem though.  I have two pages.

One a Python Page and the other an Html Page with JQuery

Can someone please tell me how I can get my ajax post to work correctly.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        alert('Im going to start processing');

        $.ajax({
            url: "saveList.py",
            type: "post",
            data: {'param':{"hello":"world"}},
            dataType: "application/json",
            success : function(response)
            {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Python Code

```
import sys
import json

def index(req):
    result = {'success':'true','message':'The Command Completed Successfully'};

    data = sys.stdin.read();

    myjson = json.loads(data);

    return str(myjson);
```

Comment: Presumably, nothing happens? Please tell us the problems you see.

Comment: Are you posting a JSON or a JSON-string which is percentile-encoded?

Comment: I just want it so it shows me what I posted in so I have an idea that it actually works.  Insted of it at present returning "null"

Comment: @Deano Well, your question first was not very clear. Now you can check the updated version of my answer. It should work.

Comment: Why is there a semicolon after each statement in the python code above? An error, I assume?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, let's move to your updated question.

First, you should pass Ajax data property in string representation. Then, since you mix `dataType` and `contentType` properties, change `dataType` value to `"json"`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "saveList.py",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify({'param':{"hello":"world"}}),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Finally, modify your code a bit to work with JSON request as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, json

result = {'success':'true','message':'The Command Completed Successfully'};

myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)
# Do something with 'myjson' object

print 'Content-Type: application/json\n\n'
print json.dumps(result)    # or "json.dump(result, sys.stdout)"
```

As a result, in the `success` handler of Ajax request you will receive object with `success` and `message` properties.

Comment: He is posting an `application/json` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. His way of reading from stdin is correct (IMO). I suppose problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Thrustmaster What are you talking about? Default contentType for *standard* Ajax request is exaclty `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Why do you need to use something else?

Comment: OP is (from his code) doing a HTTP/POST with JSON-string in the body of HTTP. The content-type will be `application/json` which would need to be set using `$.ajax({contentType:"application/json"},...)`. What you suggested up there, is to url-encode JSON string, which, IMO, is not OP is doing (since he is correctly reading from stdin on the server-side for that)

Comment: First, are you sure that he reads from `stdin` correctly? HTTP request is not the same as input from the console. Next, he can easily send not a string but `data : { first : 1, next : 2 }` and get both `first` and `next` with `form` on server-side. What is the problem? Then, where have you taken that OP sends `application/json` as content type? Why to do it? OP simply doesn't know how to handle post requests from Ajax with plain Python CGI. I think you overdo it.

Comment: Post-data of any HTTP request is read from stdin. It is *similar* to reading from console. In this case, OP sends JSON-string (as his first line in the question says). And he is also reading it as it is meant to be. This is what I meant. Anyways, looks like OP has got it working, so lets just close this here. :)

Comment: I think you forgot about the [structure of HTTP request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5). For using `stdin` and before parsing JSON, you need first to parse the request data and get the message part from it. Simply `cgi` module does it for you, so his usage of `stdin` is not really correct and in place. And there is no difference on what content type he used for sending the request. That's what I meant :) Yep, the issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11641/discussion-between-thrustmaster-and-vision)

Comment: I have been searching the web to find how to make cgi recognise raw strings NOT sent from an html form but found this solution..my 3 days of late night sleep came to an end..thank you

Answer (score 8):

You should read json data like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import json

content_len = int(os.environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"])

req_body = sys.stdin.read(content_len)
my_dict = json.loads(req_body)
```

---

With the following code, you can run into problems:

```
 myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)
```

or written less succinctly:

```
requ_body = sys.stdin.read()
my_dict = json.load(requ_body)
```

That *does* work for me when my cgi script is on an `apache` server, but you can't count on that working in general--as I found out when my cgi script was on another server. According to the cgi spec:

```
RFC 3875                    CGI Version 1.1                 October 2004


4.2.  Request Message-Body

   Request data is accessed by the script in a system-defined method;
   unless defined otherwise, this will be by reading the 'standard
   input' file descriptor or file handle.

      Request-Data   = [ request-body ] [ extension-data ]
      request-body   = <CONTENT_LENGTH>OCTET
      extension-data = *OCTET

   A request-body is supplied with the request if the CONTENT_LENGTH is
   not NULL.  The server MUST make at least that many bytes available
   for the script to read.  The server MAY signal an end-of-file
   condition after CONTENT_LENGTH bytes have been read or it MAY supply
   extension data.  Therefore, the script MUST NOT attempt to read more
   than CONTENT_LENGTH bytes, even if more data is available.  However,
   it is not obliged to read any of the data.
```

The key line is:

> the script MUST NOT attempt to read more
>   than CONTENT_LENGTH bytes, even if more data is available.

Apparently, `apache` sends an eof signal to the cgi script immediately after sending the request body to the cgi script, which causes `sys.stdin.read()` to return.  But according to the cgi spec, a server is not required to send an eof signal after the body of the request, and I found that my cgi script was hanging on `sys.stdin.read()`--when my script was on another server, which eventually caused a timeout error.

Therefore, in order to read in json data in the general case, you should do this:

```
content_len = int(os.environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"])

req_body = sys.stdin.read(content_len)
my_dict = json.loads(req_body)
```

The server sets a bunch of environment variables for cgi scripts, which contain header information, one of which is CONTENT_LENGTH.

Here is what a failed curl request looked like when I used `myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)`:

```
-v      verbose output
-H      specify one header
--data  implicitly specifies a POST request 

Note that curl automatically calculates a Content-Length header 
for you.
```

---

```
~$ curl -v \
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> --data '{"a": 1, "b": 2}' \
> http://localhost:65451/cgi-bin/1.py

*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 65451 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 65451 (#0)
> POST /cgi-bin/1.py HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:65451
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 16
> 
* upload completely sent off: 16 out of 16 bytes

=== hung here for about 5 seconds ====

< HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
< Date: Thu, 08 Mar 2018 17:53:30 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: inets/6.4.5
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little bit to the great @7stud's answer
I had some problems with content length when reading unicode which I fixed by reading from buffer:

```
content_length = int(os.environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"])
data = sys.stdin.buffer.read(content_length).decode('utf-8')
```