# JSON Post from JQuery to Python Unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, json

I have HTML code that calls the Javascript code "map_stations.js". Map_stations.js uses lat/lon coordinates from master_file.csv to place several markers on a Google Map and add event listeners to them:

```
function mapStations(map) {
    $.get('master_file.csv',function(data) {
        getStations(data,map)
     });
}

function getStations(data,map) {

    ... 

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function () {
        $.getScript('plot.js', function () {})
    })

    ...
}
```

Within plot.js, I'm currently editing the code to ping Python using Ajax and get some sort of reply:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/pycode/etsurge.py',
    type'post',
    dataType:'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({'key1':'value1'}),
    success: function(response){alert('hi');
                                makePlot(response.data);}
```

map_stations.js successfully calls makePlot() if I take out the Ajax call, so I know that these two scripts work. It's just my inability to correctly code the Ajax call that's causing trouble. Here's the Python code:

```
import sys
import json
import cgi

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

result = {}
result['success'] = True

d = {}
for k in fs.keys():
    d[k] = fs.getvalue(k):

result['data'] = d

sys.stdout.write('Content-Type: application/json\n\n')
sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result))
sys.stdout.close()
```

The Python code goes on to do other stuff and I've tested it to make sure it runs with no errors. It prints empty output from the above commands when I run it by itself.

I've copied the above Ajax/Json related code directly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721244/ajax-posting-to-python-cgi), however I can't seem to get a successful Ajax call. Could it have something to do with nesting a $.ajax within a $.getScript within a $.get? If so, how do I fix it? If not, what else could it be?

Comment: Do you get a 500 error?  I would check your server logs.  These kinds of problems can be a pain to debug, and are as likely to involve the server configuration as your actual code.

Comment: @BrenBarn, Thanks. I'll talk to the boss about that and see what we find (I don't have full permissions to view the logs apparently; that would be too easy).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the cgi-bin was lacking some necessary items.