# Read JSON data with python cgi

Tags: android, python, json, cgi

For some reason I find how to read json data in my cgi script.

I'm sending the json through an android application like this:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler<String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(serverUrl + "/cgi-bin/save.py");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
        String time = sdf.format(camera.getRecordTime().getTime());

        json.put("md", camera.isMdOn());
        json.put("threshold", camera.getThreshold());
        json.put("recordTime", time);

        postMethod.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
        String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod, resonseHandler);

        Log.e("response :", response);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and my script is:

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe

import cgi, sys, json

#data = cgi.FieldStorage()
#data = sys.stdin.read()


print "Content-type: application/json"
print 
response={'result': data['md']}
print(json.JSONEncoder().encode(response))
```

as you can see I tried several methods (`cgi.FieldStorage()`, `sys.stdin.read()`)
but nothing works, I'm getting a `500` error. I'm able to send data back from the script but not to read data sent to the script.

I know I can use a framework but I don't want to, so please don't refer me to any of those.

Comment: Have you looked at [other related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718572/post-json-to-python-cgi)?

Comment: Yes. That's why I'm posting this question.

Comment: @nerdwaller I also tried the suggested solution with myjson = json.load(sys.stdin) but I'm getting no response back from the server, It's just get's stuck.